# Java Socket Permissions - java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: java, sockets, sandbox, java-security

I am having trouble making a client server to run  in a sandbox, where it is only allowed that the connections between client/server only happen in one specific port.

In my code I only use port number: 23456, and this happens in the server console:

```
*Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:52267" "accept,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)*
```

---

This is what I have in my client sandbox:

```
grant {

    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:23456", "accept, listen, connect, resolve";
    (..)
    };
```

this is what I have in my server sandbox:

```
grant {

permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:23456", "accept, listen, connect, resolve";
(...)
};
```

Comment: In your code you are using port 52267.

Comment: No, I'm using port 23456 in both server and client